# Meta key does not work

Tags: macos, emacs, key-bindings

I'm trying M-w (command -w) on my mac Air, but get requests to terminate my terminal process.Then I found on internet that on some computer it uses `option`. I tried that but still not working.I'm trying to copy file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the Terminal, there is an option under Terminal Settings > Keyboard to "Use Option As Meta key". Select that and you'll be able to use the option key for things like M-w. Personally, I find that I want to have both CTRL and META on both sides of the keyboard, so I map the "command" key to be "control" and "control" to be "command" using the System Preferences Keyboard pane, leaving the "option" key to be a "Meta" on both sides of the spacebar. This allows me to work fluidly without having to strike two keys with one hand, which saves me a lot of ergonomic distress.

Some people like to use the caps lock as a control key, which has the advantage of increased ease of access to the control key on the left side, but it has three major disadvantages in my view. First, it gives an asymmetry, which I find reduces fluidity of typing. Second, it costs you a caps lock key, which I use for example when I have to type out a named constant (rather than holding down a shift key to type out something like SELECTION_CATEGORY_RESTRICTION_ELEMENT, which I would prefer to be able to touch-type). Third, it tends to encourage the use of certain left-hand key chords, which in my experience has led to extremely painful repetitive strain injuries.
Because of the latter, in particular, I do not recommend remapping the caps lock key to CTRL, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Caps Lock as Ctrl is good for people who still want to type single-handed chords like `C-s`. The primary goal being simply to avoid using the little finger on the modifier key. I agree that two-handed modifier use is a very sensible approach, but even then Caps Lock may prove a more agreeable left Ctrl key, as with its usual home-row positioning, it's a just a jump to the left.

Comment: @phils I can see that, and I mention it for those who are interested in pursuing it - however, having once messed up my hands severely due to overuse of key chords of that sort, I can no longer recommend that sort of approach in good conscience. (my hands are better now, for which I am properly grateful, but it was a painful period)

Comment: Editing my answer to be a little less of a jerk about it, though.